# want to pass assertions for deleting

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to assert the webtable whenever i delete or edit the row in webtable.To assert insertion i used assert `size1==size-1`, for deleting am trying d same with decrement op..but its failing

```
def discovr_attri_delete(self):
    driver = self.driver  
    driver.switch_to_default_content()


    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#dijit__TreeNode_51_label").click()

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#dijit__TreeNode_54_label").click() 
    driver.switch_to_frame("main")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dojox_grid__TreeView_1']/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#deleteButton_label").click()
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
    webtable=driver.find_element_by_class_name("dojoxGridScrollbox")      
    size1 = len(webtable.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"))
    assert size1==size-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Root Cause: you are getting `size1` after deleting and comparing `size1` with `size1-1` which never result `true`.

**How to fix it:** There are 2 options.

*Option 1:*

You have to either pass the `orginalSize` to the `discovr_attri_delete` method and compare the originalSize with currentSize.

*Option 2:* (Preferable)

Get the `originalSize` before deleting (after switching to the frame) and then compare the row count after deleting.

Comment: You need a 2 step verification for edit. Step1: Get the originalValue and compare with the value that you are going to edit with (if both are same then there is no point of edit). Step 2: Get the modifiedValue and compare with the value that you used to edit (if both matched then validation passed). Alternatively you can also compare originalValue with modifiedValue in step 2.